# How do I replace all bad values in an xr array based on QC array?

Tags: python, indexing, python-xarray

I have the following dataset in xarray:

```
sauz
Out[484]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                 (N_PROF: 432, N_LEVELS: 1994, N_PARAM: 25)
Dimensions without coordinates: N_PROF, N_LEVELS, N_PARAM
Data variables: (12/45)
    PRES_ADJUSTED           (N_PROF, N_LEVELS) float32 ...
    PRES_ADJUSTED_QC        (N_PROF, N_LEVELS) object b'1' b'1' b'1' ... nan nan
    PRES_ADJUSTED_ERROR     (N_PROF, N_LEVELS) float32 ...
    TEMP_ADJUSTED           (N_PROF, N_LEVELS) float32 ...
    TEMP_ADJUSTED_QC        (N_PROF, N_LEVELS) object b'1' b'1' b'8' ... nan nan
    TEMP_ADJUSTED_ERROR     (N_PROF, N_LEVELS) float32 ...
                     ...
    PLATFORM_NUMBER         (N_PROF) object ...
    CYCLE_NUMBER            (N_PROF) float64 ...
    PI_NAME                 (N_PROF) |S64 ...
    STATION_PARAMETERS      (N_PROF, N_PARAM) object ...
    WMO_INST_TYPE           (N_PROF) object ...
    DATA_CENTRE             (N_PROF) object ...
```

Each variable has an associated `_QC` column. I need to go into each `_QC` column to fetch the index of any value different than `1` or `nan` to then go into the actual variable array and replace the values at these bad flag indices to `nan`.

I have no idea how to do that!

Thanks a lot for the help